# Errors executing Visual Studio Code in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ssh, gui, putty

I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04 64bit with Putty and xming to ssh into. At the moment these are the error messages I'm getting when I run VSCode. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode in multiple ways but it is not working and coming up with the same error messages.

```
leo@ansible:~/tools/web/visual-studio-code$ ./Code
[22021:0822/155353:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(173)] Running without the SUID 
sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more 
information on developing with the sandbox on.
[22021:0822/155356:INFO:audio_manager_pulse.cc(258)] Failed to connect to the context.  
Error: Connection refused
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
ome/leo/tools/web/visual-studio-code/Code: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274:
poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
leo@ansible:~/tools/web/visual-studio-code$[22039:0822/155357:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(347)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[22039:0822/155357:ERROR:gl_surface_x11.cc(56)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[22039:0822/155357:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(340)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple 
threads in process gpu-process
[22039:0822/155357:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(37)]  MessageAttachmentSet destroyed 
with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
```

Can I expect to run Visual Studio Code from a headless server? and receive a GUI to work with?

Comment: Assuming you have X11 Forwarding enabled, also try enabling `ForwardX11Trusted` (`ssh  -Y`, dunno what the option for Putty is). Though why you would run Visual Studio Code when you have a Windows box beats me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expects an X server to run with. You can't run that headless. I guess you want to edit something on gui.
You can do this over FTP/Samba/SCP, edit on your PC and transfer it back to the server.

Comment: XMing is the X Server in this instance is it not?